# Паттерн на запрет латиницы или кириллицы

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть небольшая задача, есть input в форме, этот input должен принимать только латинские символы, или только кириллицу, использование латиницы и кириллицы одновременно не должно допускаться.

Как это реализовать через js или php?

Comment: почитайте про RegExp

Comment: @Big_Energy язык определяется по первой введённой букве? Т.е., если пользователь начал вводить английские буквы, то уже не может далее ввести русские? А если начал вводить русские символы, то тогда срабатывает фильтр для английских, так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *input должен принимать только латинские символы, или только кириллицу, использование латиницы и кириллицы одновременно не должно допускаться*

Напишите два шаблона для кириллицы и латиницы по отдельности, и сравнивайте их в условии с помощью исключающего оператора `XOR`:

```
$str = 'Русские и English';

$ru = preg_match('~[а-яё]+~iu', $str);
$en = preg_match('~[a-z]+~i', $str);

if (! ($ru ^ $en) ) {
    die('Используйте или кириллицу, или латиницу!');
}

echo 'Всё ок!';
```

В этом примере результат будет таким:

```
Используйте или кириллицу, или латиницу!
```

---

В JS принцип тот же:

```js
var str = 'Русские и English';

var ru = /[а-яё]+/i.test(str);
var en = /[a-z]+/i.test(str);

if (! (ru ^ en) ) {
    alert("Используйте или кириллицу, или латиницу!");
} else {
    alert("Всё ок!");
}
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо! А как на js такое реализовать, не подскажите?

Comment: @Big_Energy дописал пример на JS.

Answer (score 1):

Русские буквы:

```
<input id="userfnamesignup" type="text" pattern="[\u0400-\u04ff]{3,30}"
     name="user_fname" placeholder="Enter your name please" required />
<input type=submit>
```

Английские буквы:

```
<input id="userfnamesignup" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,30}"
    name="user_fname" placeholder="Enter your name please" required />
<input type=submit>
```

С учетом уточнения можно так:
Для английский слов

```
<input class="input" maxlength="40" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
$('.input').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
    }
});
```

Для русских слов

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {
    if (!this.value.match(/^[\u0400-\u04ff]+$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04ff]/g, '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Это понятно, мне нужно чтобы в поле можно было ввести ТОЛЬКО англ или ТОЛЬКО русс символы, использование англ и русс символов (пример: "Тестовый Test") не должно допускаться

Comment: @Big_Energy Паттерн не позволит засабмитить, если есть русские и английские буквы одновременно. Или вы имеете ввиду, что вы хотите через event контролировать, что вообще добавляется в input? какие символы попадают?

Comment: @Big_Energy Поправил - теперь вообще невозможно вставить что-то кроме русских или английских букв.